# Density of states LL in graphene

Tags: solid-state-physics, computational-physics, graphene, density-of-states

I am using the Kernel Polynomial Method to determine the spectral density of a 2DEG system that has been sujected to a perpendicular magnetic field B.
I wish to determine

(a) What the amplitudes of the delta functions of the graphs are (l assume it is directly linked to the degeneracy of each energy level, but the KPM documentation suggests it is some sort of operator. Moreover it could also be the case that it is just the numerical solutions of the delta functions and that it has no physical meaning), and

(b) I wish to determine the effect of the amplitude of the magnetic field to the DoS.

[image]